# Issues with the jQuery `this` selector

Tags: jquery

I've just started with jQuery. I'm building a form that is inside a table row that is out putted by PHP.

I need to get the time outputted by PHP in the table cell. But I cannot get the jQuery `this` selector to work. I was able to use it to get the attribute of the form I submitted, but I cannot get any of the child elements. I have tried, `$("td.time", this).html();` and `$(this).find("td.time").html();` and even the children selector. All three always return the value undefined. For testing I removed the this and just grabbed the first element and it returned the contents of the div. Here is some of my code.

The table runs like so:

```
<table>
  <form id="[ever changing]" class="users">
    <tr>
        <td class="time">2014-04-28 23:57:03</td>
    <tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

jQuery tries to grab it here:

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.users", function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var time = $("td.time", this).html();
});
```

It always returns undefined, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to pass define event variable as `function(event)`. As event is undefined you are getting error.

Comment: @Palmer Can you post complete html which is inside the form? Is it the complete html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `form` you need to `embed` `td` with `table` otherwise `td` will get removed from `form`

HTML

```
<form id="[ever changing]" class="users">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">2014-04-28 23:57:03</td>
        <tr>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </table>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.users", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var time = $(this).find("td.time").html();
  console.log(time);
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/8br8h/)**

Answer (score 1):

You missed the event in the `function(event){`

```
  $(document).on("submit", "form.users", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var time = $("td.time", this).html();
    });
```

Comment: That was not the problem, I am still getting an undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you havenot added the table tag yet. So when the browser renders the html it will not add the td tag . Instead it will just look like as follows , if you inspect the html source

```
 <form class="users" id="[ever changing]">

     2014-04-28 23:57:03    
</form>
```